# webpack sass-loader doesnt recognize scss method

Tags: sass, webpack, libsass, node-sass

```
  "name": "sass-loader",
  "version": "2.0.1",
  "description": "Sass loader for webpack"
```

sass-loader doesn't compile scss built in method - selector-parse [http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#selector_parse-instance_method]

```
 ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./js/symbols/svg/toggles/switch.scss
Module build failed: 
    @each $selector in selector-parse(#{&}) {
    ^
      Invalid selector after .show-on-all-pagesselector-parse
```

any ideas? does node-sass support these built in scss methods? what loader should I use? Is there a webpack loader based on sass command line like grunt-contrib-sass?

Comment: This can be solved by editing the webpack sass-loader. node-sass supports v3 functions by adding in the options parameters an object of with mapping of functions ( see: functions (>= v3.0.0) section at https://github.com/sass/node-sass#functions--v300)

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by editing the webpack sass-loader.

**node-sass** supports **v3 functions** (experimental feature).

Can be done by adding in the options parameters an object with mapping of functions to run.

see: **functions (>= v3.0.0)** section at [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#functions--v300)